# Looping through json file

Tags: c#

I have a json result I am trying to loop through, but it seems to be exiting out of my foreach, here is my json result

```
{
    "word": "example",
    "results": [{
        "definition": "a representative form or pattern",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["model"],
        "typeOf": ["representation", "internal representation", "mental representation"],
        "hasTypes": ["prefiguration", "archetype", "epitome", "guide", "holotype", "image", "loadstar", "lodestar", "microcosm", "original", "paradigm", "pilot", "prototype", "template", "templet", "type specimen"],
        "derivation": ["exemplify"],
        "examples": ["I profited from his example"]
    }, {
        "definition": "something to be imitated",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["exemplar", "good example", "model"],
        "typeOf": ["ideal"],
        "hasTypes": ["pacemaker", "pattern", "beauty", "prodigy", "beaut", "pacesetter"],
        "derivation": ["exemplify", "exemplary"]
    }, {
        "definition": "an occurrence of something",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["case", "instance"],
        "typeOf": ["happening", "natural event", "occurrence", "occurrent"],
        "hasTypes": ["clip", "mortification", "piece", "time", "humiliation", "bit"],
        "derivation": ["exemplify"],
        "examples": ["but there is always the famous example of the Smiths"]
    }, {
        "definition": "an item of information that is typical of a class or group",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["illustration", "instance", "representative"],
        "typeOf": ["information"],
        "hasTypes": ["excuse", "apology", "specimen", "case in point", "sample", "exception", "quintessence", "precedent"],
        "derivation": ["exemplify", "exemplary"],
        "examples": ["this patient provides a typical example of the syndrome", "there is an example on page 10"]
    }, {
        "definition": "punishment intended as a warning to others",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["deterrent example", "lesson", "object lesson"],
        "typeOf": ["monition", "admonition", "word of advice", "warning"],
        "derivation": ["exemplary"],
        "examples": ["they decided to make an example of him"]
    }, {
        "definition": "a task performed or problem solved in order to develop skill or understanding",
        "partOfSpeech": "noun",
        "synonyms": ["exercise"],
        "typeOf": ["lesson"],
        "examples": ["you must work the examples at the end of each chapter in the textbook"]
    }],
    "syllables": {
        "count": 3,
        "list": ["ex", "am", "ple"]
    },
    "pronunciation": {
        "all": "ɪɡ'zæmpəl"
    },
    "frequency": 4.67
}
```

My code below, get the json string in to a dynamic variable, to loop through results (well at least I am trying

```
    dynamic words = JObject.Parse(responseString);

    if (words.results != null)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (dynamic example in words.results)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("result");
                if (example.partOfSpeech != null)
                {
                    builder.AppendText("Type");
                    builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(10000000));
                    builder.AppendText(example.partOfSpeech);
                    builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(10000000));
                }
                MessageBox.Show("result");
                if (example.definition != null)
                {
                    builder.AppendText("Definition");
                    builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(10000000));
                    builder.AppendText(example.definition);
                    builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(10000000));
                }
                MessageBox.Show("result");

                if (example.examples != null)
                {
                    builder.AppendText("Example sentence");
                    builder.AppendBreak(new TimeSpan(10000000));
                    builder.AppendText(example.examples[0]);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("result");
            }
        }
    }
```

I am rying to loop through each result, but it doesn't seem to be doing it with my code, how can

I loop through results?

Comment: Does words.results return null? Are your try contents throwing an exception? Help us out here

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, that code works for me - minus the builder it's iterating through correctly.

Comment: @CallumBradbury I am getting the following error: http://i.imgur.com/1Oh5NEM.png

Comment: it's an issue with your builder, not your json. Perhaps isolate the builder, and ask a question about that

Comment: @CallumBradbury it can't be though, because if I put it inside a messagebox I get the same error too http://i.imgur.com/tZXhv5z.png

Comment: Interesting. I fixed it by adding (string) before the variable http://i.imgur.com/7WP5bSQ.png